# Java installation failed on Mac

Tags: java, macos, installation, macos-sierra

I'm attempting to install JDK 8 Update 121.pkg on a Mac running macOS Sierra 10.12.3.

The installer produces the following error message, see screenshot:
["The installation failed... Contact the software manufacturer for assistance."](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W2fYO.png)

How would I contact Oracle? Or is there a better fix?

Comment: I think a simple Google search would provide better results than members' opinions on a coding website

Comment: Try `brew cask install java`.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you use [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) and a tool like [jenv](http://www.jenv.be/) to manage the different Java versions on OSX:

```
brew cask install java
brew install jenv
```

OSX needs its outdated system-default Java for the occasional task, so you don't want to go replacing it outright.